# What is the difference of the List declaration?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, get

This line reports the methods of `Load` like `Load.getId()`:

```
List<Load> dbRecs = dbList.getAllLoads();
```

Whereas this line reports a incremental hex address

```
List dbRecs = dbList.getAllLoads();
log.d("Load", dbRecs);
```

Now the project can move along.

Is the first line posting correct because I supplied a correct structure for the `List` declaration of `List<Load>`?
I could just plow forward but I want a short definitive answer or a specific doc link.

Comment: Read up on generics.

Comment: I think you need to restructure this into a specific question. 
Perhaps try the format of: What you did, what you were expecting, and  what you actually got.

Comment: Yes, I understand the semantics of this site. But my fustration led me more towards a solution. I upvoted the first answer for the benefit of any one who might read this. I appreciate your comment greatly and will benefit from this advice in the future. But this question suffers from some many others about the same subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first declaration employs [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). It's a syntactic sugaring that allows you to declare that this is a list of `Load`s, and not just any other odd object, and have the compiler prevent you from adding `Integer`s or `String`s there by mistake. It also allows you to save some hassle and get `Load` objects directly from it instead of having to mess around with casts.

If possible, using generics is usually considered the best practice.

Comment: And here is the horrible question about odd objects. Without using generics how would one go about getting to the methods in the List then? Or is that even possible? I come from an assembly language background on PCs, midteirs and mainframes.

Comment: Mureinik, Can you make this the answer? Or do I do it? Thank you.